# How to implement edit action in controller if I don't yet have an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am developing my first Rails application, which tracks job statuses for a job shop. I have the following models:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
  ...
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

I would like to have a page with a form that accepts a scanned barcode as input. It would find the `Part` object in the DB using the barcode ID and would set the `Part.completed_at` attribute to the current time.

I am trying to keep everything as RESTful as possible, and so at first it would seem like this page should be a view for the edit action in the Parts controller. However, in this view I don't yet have the `Part` object. What is the best way to implement this functionality? Should it be a new action in the Parts controller called something like `find_and_update`? Thanks in advance for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a new non-RESTful action called `find_and_update`, that will work just fine.

If you want to keep it RESTful:

1) you could have a `PartCompletions` controller, that has a `create` action that accepts an ID. That is to say, when you submit a barcode, you are "creating" a "part completion". One of the light-bulb moments people have learning REST with Rails is when they learn that your RESTful controllers don't have to map 1-to-1 with your models / database tables. You can create new abstractions to help stick to the RESTful verbs (create, read, update, delete).

2) If you didn't want to create an extra controller, you could use the `update` method of your existing `PartsController`. That is to say, you're "updating" a "part" and giving it some new values (in this case a new completed_at date). You'd pass it the id from the barcode reader, and also pass it a hash with the new values you want to change (ie, that'd mean passing in the completed at field with the current time in your post request, rather than setting it in your controller action)

Either of these two approaches can be fine - as is the non-RESTful option, too - it depends on how big your app is, how many other non-RESTful actions you're likely to end up having if you don't strictly follow REST, etc. The smaller and more self-contained your app is, the more it's OK to break REST and other conventions/patterns in order to save time and keep it simple up front. My advice: don't spend too long agonising over which approach is the best. Pick one, and write code. You can re-factor it later.